# python pre-test do while syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop

this is my program for some reason I keep getting a syntax error at while, please help me sort this out

```
#Variables
Destination = " "
MilesDest = 0
MPG = 0
GallonCost = 0
GallonsNeeded = 0
GasCost = 0
Syntel = " "

#Below begins Do-While pre-test
while Syntel != "No":
    Syntel = str(input("would you like to run this program?(Yes/No)(Case-Sensitive) "))
    Destination = str(input("Enter the name of your destination: "))
    MilesDest = float(input("Enter the amount of miles between your starting point and your destination: "))
    MPG = float(input("Enter the current MPG your car gets: "))
    GallonCost = float(input("Enter the current cost for a gallon of gas: "))
    GallonsNeeded = MilesDest/MPG
    GasCost = GallonCost*GallonsNeeded
    print("The number of gallons it takes to get to ",Destination, " is ",GallonsNeeded)
    print("The cost of the trip to ",Destination, " is $",GasCost)
 #Salutation
print("Thank you for using my program, good bye")
```

Comment: You are missing *two* closing parentheses on the `Syntel = str(input(...` line preceding the `while` statement. Your indentation is a mess, making it hard for us to say much about your post, and you did not include the actual error message.

Comment: getting a syntax error at my 2nd print

Comment: Again, look at the preceding line. You are missing more closing parentheses.

Comment: Fixed that, now getting an error at the quotation after "is" in my first print statement

Comment: This is *not* an interactive debugging service; I already voted to close your question as typo errors are not useful to future visitors.

Comment: You are right, thank you for your assistance, I didn't properly space my code in the actual question itself. I had it correct in my python. I guess I'll just have to post another question.

Comment: You are missing commas after `Destination` in both print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `while Syntel != "No":`. Missing the `:`.

You're also missing closing brackets `))` on the `Syntel =` line.

Note that once you correct that, the program will run forever.

Comment: Update: getting syntax error now at 2nd print

Comment: General syntax error debugging tip: If you're getting a syntax error on a particular line that looks OK, take a look at the previous line.